# Node.js multi package project?

Tags: node.js, npm, project-structure

I'm new to Node, coming from a Java background. These days I'm experimenting with each part of a full application: database, rest api, ui.

So far I wrote the database-backed logic, which runs on its own, processes text files, store data about them in the database and exposes a REST API to query that data. I'm now going to make the ui to navigate that data.

Would it be reasonable having a structure like this:

```
- (a) main project folder
    - (b) backend application (a Restify server responds to REST calls querying the database)
    - (c) ui application (an http server serves React static files)
```

If that makes sense, I would guess that:

- (b) has a `package.json` with server- and rest- related dependencies (i.e. Restify, MongoDB, ...)
- (c) has another `package.json` with dependencies for ui (i.e. React, Webpack, etc, but not Restify or MongoDB)
- (a) has a third `package.json` which cares for installing each sub-project (I'd say by running `npm install` through hand-written *npm-scripts*).
  Otherwise, how do you usually handle such Node projects? Do you keep each application completely separate from the rest?

For those who know that tool, this mimics a Maven multi-module project; though that level of automation is not needed, I'd just like to come up with a self-contained package.

Comment: Thanks @watery for this excellent question! Can you share your end result?

Comment: @barfuin As usually happens with commercial projects, I've soon been set on another one, so I hadn't had a chance to try anything :-) But I'll report here as soon as I can find something.

Comment: @barfuin I started a new project where I'm extracting parts of an existing monolithic application into separate packages (ui components, icons, etc), as subfolders beside the main application folder; Lerna helps use them as local dependencies (though it may feel a bit strange at times, i.e. you can only add one dependency at a time, there's no uninstall command, but npm uninstall breaks because local dependencies are declared as regular ones); there's no support though for application packaging / deploying AFAICT - and it is said in several issues that Lerna is not a deployment tool.

Answer (score 11):

These project structures are called as monorepos - A single node project repository that contains multiple packages. There are tools like [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/). If you are using yarn as package manager, it comes with experimental feature of [workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/).

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently using webpack, but I'll have a look at both.

Comment: Back after some Lerna experience. You may find my impressions in my comment to my own question. It seems Lerna only covers half of my requirements, offering no packaging / deployments facilities; but then even a tool like Gulp (for what I've seen) doesn't provide any kind of project structure / lifecycle (a la Maven so to speak), in fact I ended up writing my own copy-this-zip-that-upload-those-there script.